# Where can I download JSTL jar

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, jstl

Does anyone know because all the places I've tried seem to timeout!

Comment: You can find download links in [our JSTL wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info).

Answer (score 80):

You can download JSTL 1.1 [here](http://archive.apache.org/dist/jakarta/taglibs/standard/binaries/jakarta-taglibs-standard-1.1.2.zip) and JSTL 1.2 [here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar).

#### See also:

- [JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)

Comment: exactly what i used for schoolwork too. worked great.

Comment: nope! i havent checked all the links but half of them not working

Comment: Link changed. Hope it works now.

Comment: All the links are working fine

Answer (score 6):

http://jstl.java.net/download.html

It's been split into two separate JAR files: jstl-api.jar and jstl-impl.jar.

Answer (score 4):

In the past, there was something like: https: //jstl.dev.java.net/download.html. But since a few days, there is something happening on dev.java.net.

Java.net will be modified, read this: http: //www.java.net/. So I think we have to wait. I also found: http: //java.net/projects/help/pages/RequestedProjects.

Maybe this is helpful.

Another option is to look into the maven repository: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/

Answer (score 4):

http://archive.apache.org/dist/jakarta/taglibs/standard/binaries/

None of the mirrors work on the other page

Answer (score 4):

You can downlod JSTL jar from this link

```
http://findjar.com/jar/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar.html
```

Answer (score 2):

If youre using Maven, here's something for your pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Visit [Here](http://www.findjar.com/index.x?query=jstl+)  to get your required jar files of JSTL.

and to get any of your required jar files visit [HERE](http://www.findjar.com/index.x)