# JSP include doesnt work, jstl import work, so what difference does it make?

Tags: jsp, jstl

JSP include doesnt work, jstl import work, so what difference does it make?

I am using WAS 7 server, any clue folks?

Comment: Come on. Show us the code at least. We're not extra-lucid.

Comment: Agreed, "doesn't work" is not really an accurate problem description.

Answer (score -1):

Its not entirely clear that you have an uncommon problem : I would assume that, given the simplicity of the question ,  you have not added all the necessary JSTL / JSP jars to the class path .

[Where can I download JSTL jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292914/where-can-i-download-jstl-jar)

Comment: The JSTL import does work. It's the JSP include that doesn't work.

Comment: He should not need it with WAS7 any way.