# JSTL - Output not coming as expected

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Below is the code I have in index.jsp using jstl 1.2.

```
 <%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"%>
 <% String[] setName = {"Hello", "you", "are", "using", "jstl", "in", "jsp"};
 request.setAttribute("getName", setName);
 %>
 <html>
 <body>
 <table>
 <tr><td>Print</td></tr>
 <c:forEach var="itemName" items="#{getName}" >
 <tr>
 <td>${itemName}</td>
 </tr>
 </c:forEach>
 </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

The output I was expecting is as below

```
 Print
 Hello
 you
 are
 using
 jstl
 in
 jsp
```

However below is what I am getting

```
  Print
  #{name}
```

Please let me know where I am missing

Below is the only jar file I have in WEB-INF/lib folder
     jstl-1.2.jar

Thanks in advance

**Fahim**

**Note:** Adding Java and JSP tag as person who have knowledge of Java and JSP might be knowing **JSTL** too...

Comment: **Please note**

When I run same code in JSF project, the code was working and showing me desired output.

Right now I am doing the same in Ecplise under Web Dynamic Project

**Am I missing any jar files??**

Comment: Well well well, I got the problem...

I should have used `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>` instead of `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here,

```html
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"%>
```

You're specifying the wrong JSTL taglib URL. This one is for JSTL 1.0. After JSTL 1.1 it requires a `/jsp` in the path. See also the [JSTL 1.1 tag library documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/index.html).

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

As to the of the code (and to reply on all those duplicate answers complaining to use `${}` instead), the `#{}` syntax will only work inside JSP when you're targeting a Servlet 2.5 / 2.1 compatible container with a `web.xml` conforming Servlet 2.5 spec. Tomcat 6.0 is an example of such a container. The `#{}` will indeed not work in JSP tags on older containers such as Tomcat 5.5 or older.

For clarity and to avoid confusion among starters, better use `${}` all the time in JSP tags. Also better use self-documenting variable names.

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<% 
    String[] names = {"Hello", "you", "are", "using", "jstl", "in", "jsp"};
    request.setAttribute("names", names);
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>JSTL demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr><td>Print</td></tr>
            <c:forEach items="${names}" var="name">
                <tr><td>${name}</td></tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### See also:

- [Our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)
- [Difference between JSP EL, JSF EL and Unified EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812755/difference-between-jsp-el-jsf-el-and-unified-el)

Comment: Thanks BalusC for detailed explanation...

I figured out that problem yesterday and added comment for the same...

Still thanks for sharing more information on this....

Comment: I have one question : When I was using `items=${names}`, I was getting error as **Invalid attribute (items)**.

I am using Tomcat 6.0 and Servlet version in xml is 2.5.

As you mentioned above, **For clarity and to avoid confusion among starters, better use ${} all the time in JSP tags. Also better use self-documenting variable names.**, this was not working for me as I was getting error as mentioned above...

Please suggest me what should be used ($ or #)...

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to quote it `items="${names}"`, exactly as the error message tried to tell you (and as shown in my answer)

Comment: sorry for confusion..

I was using `items="${names}"`... Still I was getting error as mentioned above...

Answer (score 0):

`#{name}` is not a valid Java variable reference - looks like you are confusing it with JQuery selector. 
Anyways try just using items="${name}"

Comment: when I use items="name" I get o/p as 
`Print
name`

Comment: NOTE: This is simple web application project and not any JSF project. In lib I have general jar file that are needed for web application so I only added jstl1.2.jar file

Let me know if I am missing any jar file here...

Also When I run the same code earlier in JSF project, it was running and showing me desired output...

Comment: Please note the QUOTES, don't forget em :)

Comment: When I use ${name}, below is exception I am getting `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp(9,33) quote symbol expected org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.jav‌​a:40)`
 
Also showing error as **Invalid attribute (items)**

Below is what I have 

`<c:forEach var="itemName" items="${name}">`

Comment: Am I missing any jar files?? Also check the note that I have added in actual post...

Comment: can you do me a favor and rename your String array from name to names and use that for your items. alternatively get rid of the request.setAttribute line i have a feeling its getting in the way.

Comment: Still `<c:forEach var="itemName" items="${names}">` saying error as `Invalid attribute(items)` and same exception

Could you post the code with changes?

Comment: is your IDE saying that its invalid attribute? If so that might be OK or a sign that you are missing a jar. Try running it.

Comment: I run and getting same exception as above....

That means the code is incorrect

@DmitryB : Actual code that I posted was running in the project which was created using JSF and this is simple Web Dynamic Project. I have feeling that I am missing some jar file or something is ODD...

Comment: yeah i feel for you. the best thing to do is start a brand new project with just JSPs and no JSF and try out your code.  The thing about JSTL and JSF tags is they get executed in different phases and can be incompatible with each other. There are plenty of articles on this topic. The best thing to do with JSF is to move on to Grails :) much easier! good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In JSTL 1.2, you don't want to use #{name} in pure JSP, that's only a JSF artifact. Instead, simply use ${name}.

Comment: When I use `${name}`, I am getting exception as `"org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp(9,33) quote symbol expected"`

Comment: also for **${name}**, I am getting error as **Invalid attribute (items)**

Answer (score 0):

`#{name}` is should be like `${name}`

oh! might be the jars related to JSTL. check thins [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292914/where-can-i-download-jstl-jar) for those jars to include in your project

Comment: When I use `${name}`, below is exception I am getting

`org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp(9,33) quote symbol expected
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)`

Comment: Also showing error as `Invalid attribute (items)`

`<c:forEach var="itemName" items="${name}">`

Comment: Either use ${requestScope.name} or try pageContext.setAttribute() instead of request.setAttribute()

Comment: Actual code that I posted was running in the project which was created using JSF and this is simple Web Dynamic Project. I have feeling that I am missing some jar file or something is ODD...

Again, what I have posted was running earlier in project that was created for JSF...

Comment: The taglib declaration is also wrong. Use `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer items using expression language like **${name}**

**U r using # instead of $ before name**

Let me know if this resolves.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the final code I am using and it is running...

Posting so that someone can use it... Might help me tomorrow ;)

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 

 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

 <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
 <% String[] setName = {"Hello", "you", "are", "using", "jstl", "in", "jsp"};
 request.setAttribute("getName", setName);
 %>
 <html>
 <body>
 <table>
 <tr><td>Print</td></tr>
 <c:forEach var="itemName" items="#{getName}">
 <tr>
 <td>${itemName}</td>
 </tr>
 </c:forEach>
 </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**Learning :** I was using `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>` instead of `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`