# how to use <c:if> in jsp file. eclipse said it is unknown tag

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags, jspinclude

I want to write a simple web page in .jsp file. I need to use `<c:if>` tag. but it is not recognized. eclipse said it is unknown tag.

I googled it and some said I need to include the standard lib (which is JSTL?).

I just want to use some basic tags in jsp file such as `<c:if>`. Do I really need to include any libraries?
If so, what libraries do I need to include? And how to do that in Eclipse?
Please let me know step by step about how to import/include these libraries or build path so that I can use `<c:if>` in my jsp file.

Comment: after some more research, I think I should put this <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %> on the top of my file so that I can use <c: > tag. right? not sure yet. I think there is something more I have to do such as build path.

Comment: What server are you using? Most servers will automatically include jstl jars in the classpath

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make sure that you have a taglib declaration in your JSP file

```
<%@ taglib
    prefix="c"
    uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" 
%>
```

Also, make sure that you've added JSTL jar files to your project classpath.

Comment: how to make sure I have JSTL jar files to my project, and if not, how to add it? I am sorry maybe this is a stupid question. I just have no idea how to do it

Comment: @user1387727 Here is how to add Jars to build path: http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29

Comment: @user1387727 And here is where to get them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292914/where-can-i-download-jstl-jar

Answer (score 5):

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<HTML>
 <HEAD><TITLE>JSTL 'if' tag</TITLE></HEAD>
 <BODY>
  <c:if test="true">Hello world!</c:if>
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Source: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JSTL/JSTLiftag.htm

Comment: I just found it and tested it. eclipse still said it is unknown tag. .

Comment: While your example is good, your HTML code doesn't follow the actual standard. Instead of just copy/pasting, show more effort and edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to see this link [JSTL tag library](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) to select the right libraries version and its header:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

or

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this tag..

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

and copy this two jar file in your project folder web-inf->lib

javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar